# CSS fluid layout - text expands over area

Tags: css, word-wrap, fluid-layout

I have the following HTML & CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/j8aFS/1/

When you decrease the window size, the red box and the text expands over the grey area because of the word wrap.

What can I do to prevent this? Can I prevent this?

What I have tried so far:

- using the CSS `white-space: nowrap;` property, but it seems that this
  isn't the best solution.
- simply leaving space below the red box, but this really influences the design too much.

What I want to achieve: The grey box should grow so the red box never expands over the grey box. The text inside the red box should not be cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to happen instead?

If you make the gray box `position relative` and set it's overflow to hidden, the red box gets cut off.

```
.div1 {
    height: 62%;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j8aFS/2/)

Unless you specify a set width for the red box, making the window smaller will cause it to get taller and overflow. You can hide it (my solution), let it overflow (current behavior) or not do the position absolute and let it make the gray box bigger. In your question it isn't clear at all what you want it to do.

[**Updated demo**](http://www.cssdesk.com/3FusC)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please note that I've edited my question above to answer your question. If I remove position absolute, the red box sits below the grey bow because of the margin. If I adjust the margin, the grey box also changes position which is not desired.

Comment: If you give `.div1` position `relative` as in the answer and leave `#div2` with position `absolute` you will get somewhat of the desired behaviour. If you do not want the red box to increase in width or height regardless of the content it contains then you will have to specify a fixed width and height and specify `overflow: hidden` to `#box2`.

Comment: @Sven still not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve.. but I updated with another demo. See if that puts you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

- You could set a `width: 180px` for your red box
- The viewport for smaller screens.
- If you would'nt position your box absolute, the box below would float down as well